# Initialize Variables as Empty

Tags: c++, initialization

When I have an `unsigned int`, but I want to find out if it is empty or not, but I need 0, I always declare it as an `int` and set it to `-1`. What am I supposed to do, though, when I need the full number spectrum or I am even working with `float`/`double`?

With some data-types it is simple, for example `std::string` which you can just compare to `""`, but is there a function to check if a variable is empty regardless of data-type, even of custom class objects?

Comment: There is no universal concept of "emptiness". **You** need to define the vocabulary that you want to use.

Comment: So what is common for `floats`?

Comment: look up `optional` (in boost or std if you can use C++17)

Comment: C++ 17? That already exists?

Comment: @kim366: If your "need the full number spectrum", there's nothing you can do, besides adding another [boolean] variable alongside your original one - just to serve as as a flag indicating whether it is empty or not. (This concept is what's encapsulated inside `std::optional`.) But keep in mind that you can keep using `-1` with `unsigned int` as long as you can sacrifice that value (which is `UINT_MAX`).

Comment: actually string is not simple. Some semantics require that '"" is not the same as 'not specified'. Not specified might mean 'use the default value', '' would mean 'use empty string'

Comment: You could be cool and just use a raw pointer, honestly I think it's fine to here.

Comment: _"C++ 17? That already exists?"_ Almost.

Comment: Compilers tend to (either completely or partially) support features from upcoming standards before the standard is officially released, usually under the standard's working name (`c++0x` for C++11, `c++1y` for C++14, and `c++1z` for C++17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of a value being missing are exactly why [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) was introduced to the C++ language specification.

```
std::optional<unsigned int> value; // by default, the value is missing
if(value) {
    // executed if the value is present, it is not
} else {
    // this code is executed
}
value = 1;
if(value) {
    // This code would now be executed
    std::cout << "the value: " << *value << std::endl;
}
```

This requires a change in thinking regarding the meaning of the variable, but it forces you to think at all times regarding whether or not the variable would be present.

So for example, if you had your own class type `MyClass` and you wanted to retain a, potentially missing, instance of it, you would do so as follows:

```
std::optional<MyClass> obj; // Initially missing
obj = MyClass();            // Assigns a newly-created instance of MyClass
obj->foo();                 // Calls the 'MyClass::foo' method
obj.reset();                // clears the 'obj' optional
```

Comment: How do you reset the variable again?

Comment: You would call the [`optional::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/reset) method on the instance.

Comment: @Kim - You reset the `value` by calling [`value.reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).  :-)

Comment: Edited to show a simple example of a user-defined type. You would have wanted to declare `a` to have been an optional such as `std::optional<int> a = 5;`

Comment: Assuming that you are using `g++` for a compiler, it depends on your compiler's version. [This page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) indicates various `g++` features and what flags are used to enable them and versions they are available in. You may also be able to use [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) if your current compiler does not yet have `std::optional` available.

Comment: Huh, now this is weird `error: 'class std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<MyClass>' has no member named 'reset'
  obj.reset();  ` This is what I get when I copy your code (and add `experimental` between `std` and `optional`).

Comment: In the file `optional` the definition of `reset` is just missing. There is `swap` and `emplace` as mentioned here, but `reset is missing.` There is only a protected `_M_reset()`

Comment: You're right, looking at the experimental optional, `reset` has not been defined. Until you can use the standard optional, you can get the same behavior by assigning an empty optional to your existing one: `a = std::optional<int>();`. If you have access to boost, it also contains a full-featured optional (as well as many other things).